# Wordpress add admin menu with more then 3 submenus

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add an admin menu with more the 3 submenu. But I can't get it to work. Please help

**Update:**
The problem is more like why is it not showing all my submenus? If you try to add 4 submenu nr 2 is gone and only showing 3 submenus. And now when I adding 9 items. They problem is repeting it slefs.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'my_menu_output' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title', 'Menu', 'manage_options', 'my-menu' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 2', 'Menu 2', 'manage_options', 'my-menu2' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 3', 'Menu 3', 'manage_options', 'my-menu3' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 4', 'Menu 4', 'manage_options', 'my-menu4' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 5', 'Menu 5', 'manage_options', 'my-menu5' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 6', 'Menu 6', 'manage_options', 'my-menu6' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 7', 'Menu 7', 'manage_options', 'my-menu7' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 8', 'Menu 8', 'manage_options', 'my-menu8' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Title 9', 'Menu 9', 'manage_options', 'my-menu9' );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check my code below

```
<?php 
add_action( 'admin_menu',  'action__admin_menu' );
function action__admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'My Plugin',
        'My Plugin',
        'manage_options',
        'my-plugin',
        'my_plugin',
    );  
    add_submenu_page(null, 
        'Sub Menu 1', 
        'Sub Menu 1', 
        'manage_options', 
        'sub-menu-1', 
        'sub_menu_1'
    ); 
    add_submenu_page(null, 
        'Sub Menu 2', 
        'Sub Menu 2', 
        'manage_options', 
        'sub-menu-2', 
        'sub_menu_2'
    ); 

}

function sub_menu_1() { ?>
    <h2>custom page 1</h2>
<?php
}

function sub_menu_2() { ?>
    <h2>custom page 2</h2>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I just tested this code and it do not work. And it's not trying to solve my problem that I can't show more the 3 subitems.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
     function clivern_plugin_top_menu(){
   add_menu_page('My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'clivern_render_plugin_page', plugins_url('/img/icon.png',__DIR__));
   add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'Custom', 'Custom', 'manage_options', __FILE__.'/custom', 'clivern_render_custom_page');
   add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'About', 'About', 'manage_options', __FILE__.'/about', 'clivern_render_about_page');
   add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'Sweet', 'Sweet', 'manage_options', __FILE__.'/sweet', 'clivern_render_sweet_page');
   add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'Test', 'Test', 'manage_options', __FILE__.'/test', 'clivern_render_test_page');
 }
 function clivern_render_plugin_page(){
  ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Plugin</h2>
   </div>
  <?php
 }
 function clivern_render_custom_page(){
   ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Custom</h2>
   </div>
   <?php
 }
 function clivern_render_about_page(){
   ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>About</h2>
   </div>
   <?php
 }
  function clivern_render_sweet_page()){
   ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Sweet Page</h2>
   </div>
   <?php
 }
  function clivern_render_test_page()){
   ?>
   <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>test_page</h2>
   </div>
   <?php
 }
 add_action('admin_menu','clivern_plugin_top_menu');
```

Comment: i just tested this code and it still only show 3 subitem.

Comment: Just updated my question to show more the problem more easy. As you can see it do not show all my submenu item

Comment: It is working check this link (https://nimb.ws/nEyOh3) I am attached screen shot

Comment: oh yes.. its something else in my code that do this.. thanks you saved my day!

Comment: It was a css error from my side. How do I mark this then?